# An Error : Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::$created_at is occurring?

Tags: php, laravel

This error is occurring even though I am passing and retrieving the object properly.
The error is in $dat. I am using it here :

```
                       <tr>
                            <th scope="row">{{$data->id}}</th>
                            <td>{{$dat->created_at}}</td>
                        </tr>


    




 public function view_giftcard_data($id){
        return view('admin.view_giftcard_data' , ['data' => Giftcards::where('id' , $id)->first() , 'dat' => Giftcard_codes::where('giftcard_id' , $id)]);
    }
```

The name of table is correct.

Comment: Is this a typo `<td>{{$dat->created_at}}</td>`? You're missing an `a` on `$dat`.

Comment: No I am returning variables data and dat from the function, I know the names are messed up but are for testing xd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because still a builder not a model, you need to take the model for example first to finish the query, like this:

```
public function view_giftcard_data($id){
        return view('admin.view_giftcard_data' , ['data' => Giftcards::where('id' , $id)->first() , 'dat' => Giftcard_codes::where('giftcard_id' , $id)->first()]);
    }
```

Comment: But I want to return all the records lying in the condition, and ->first() will only return one record. And it has a model class made.

Comment: ok, then use get() just realise its a query builder and you need a collection(maybe) to loop throw it to access fields like created_at and ...

Comment: It worked mate, thanks. I'm new to laravel so been having such small issues xd.